# SQL with regular expressions in python

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I am running this query in python. I do get the error "Invalid string literal" in the regular expression part. I know this regex is, not sure what syntax is missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
import smtplib
import sys
from IPython.core.display import HTML

PROJECT = 'server'

queryString = '''

SELECT 
  mn as mName,
  dt as DateTime,
  ip as LocalIPAddress,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, 'ActName:([\s\S\w\W]*?)ActDomain:') AS ActName,
FROM Agent.Logs

'''
```

Comment: Been a while since I've fired up Python, but have you tried placing an "r" in front of the string, it forces literal interpretation of backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this  REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, 'Account Name:(r'[\s\S\w\W]*?)Account Domain:') AS AccountName. It doesn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to match exactly? And the `r` should be before `'AccountName` not `[\s\S\w\W]*?`

Comment: Is the error coming from Python or SQL?

Comment: The error is from Python because the same SQL runs perfectly in IPython notebook. But it throws the "invalid string literal error" in Python script.

Comment: Show us the actual Python code you're running, and the full error traceback.  You're making us guess as to what your actual code is.

Comment: I have added the full code.

Comment: Again, please include a FULL ERROR TRACE in your question. "Invalid String Literal" is not enough information. If you get an error when using `r'ActName:([\s\S\w\W]*?)ActDomain:'` Please include that as well. We cannot help you with incomplete information

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an `r`

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r'ActName:([\s\S\w\W]*?)ActDomain:') AS ActName`

Comment: It doesn't work either. This query is running in IPython notebook, but now I am trying to convert it to Python script, I am getting an error in the regex part.

Comment: Whats the error and what are you trying to match? Please put this into your question and not in comments

Comment: The error is "Invalid string literal". I am trying to extract the string that is between the strings "Actname" and "ActDomain"

Comment: Please include the exact error you get when trying it with the code in my answer. And again, please put this into your question and not comments. Thank you